# Can I file a patent on my mother's name since I work for a company?

Tags: ownership, inventorship

I am employee of a company and all my work, even it is outside of work, is owned by company. I signed this common agreement while joining.

Now, I have an idea that I want to patent on my own. Since I cannot file in my name (company can claim it is theirs), I want to file with my relative's name. Does this have any complications?

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., the true inventors must be named in a patent application, even if the application is ultimately assigned to a company.  Failing to name all the true inventors or naming inventors who did not have an inventive contribution is considered fraud against the Patent Office and can result in invalidation of a patent that might issue from the application.  Be sure to consult a patent attorney before moving forward.

Comment: Not to mention a breach of the employment contract and possible theft of intellectual property against the company.

Comment: Good point.  There are lots of other non-patent related issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

> > Does this have any complications?

yes it does have complications

IMO - you have three options,

- Instead of doing something surreptitious - check with your company if
  your idea interests them. Once they confirm that they are not
  interested in it - you can file while staying employed.
- If they like your invention IMO - hand it over to them.
- Quit the company to work
  on your idea - while working on your idea - take up a part time job.